# connecting to an oracle sql database from sql developer on the same computer. When the computer is a domain computer

Tags: oracle, connectivity, listener

Hi I am trying to do DBA course that requires that I use Oracle database.

I am using my corporate pc to do it.

I set up the loopback adapter to enable localhost communication and setup the hosts file in system 32. When I start lsnrcrl

However when I try to connect I get an error.

```
<msg time='2016-07-27T08:59:00.083+02:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ABCDEF121221'
 host_addr='192.168.1.168'>

<txt>27-JUL-2016 08:59:00 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xe)(CID=(PROGRAM=SQLDeveloper)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=ABC))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=50619)) * establish * xe * 12505
 </txt>
```

Extra info

1. Listener.ora is set to localhost.
2. hostsfile in system32 is set to 192.168.1.1/domain name.ABCDEF1212221/ ABCDEF1212221

The lstnrctrl status is here.

C:\Windows\system32> lsnrctl status

```
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 27-JUL-2016  13:19:16

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 -       Production
Start Date                26-JUL-2016 15:30:00
Uptime                    0 days 21 hr. 49 min. 16 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File      C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\OLDKHQ133304\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)  (HOST=abcdefg1212221.corporate.corporate.net)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: I dont want to put in my works domain name or my computer name so domain name is just representing the correct domain name that I got from ipconfig and the computer name is the abcef1212221

Answer (score 0):

The last number of the log entry is the return code of the operation. On a successful connection, it is 0. In your case, it is 12505.

```
12505, 00000, "TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor"
// *Cause:  The listener received a request to establish a connection to a
// database or other service. The connect descriptor received by the listener
// specified a SID for an instance (usually a database instance) that either
// has not yet dynamically registered with the listener or has not been
// statically configured for the listener. This may be a temporary condition
// such as after the listener has started, but before the database instance
// has registered with the listener.
// *Action:
//  - Wait a moment and try to connect a second time.
//  - Check which instances are currently known by the listener by executing:
//    lsnrctl services <listener name>
//  - Check that the SID parameter in the connect descriptor specifies
//    an instance known by the listener.
//  - Check for an event in the listener.log file.
```

This simply means, you provided an incorrect SID.

`xe` is the default `SID` in SQL Developer.

Check the correct `SID` from the output of `lsnrctl status`, and use that for connecting.

Or even better, let's just finally forget the `SID`, and use `SERVICE_NAME`.

Another possibility is that your database instance was not started, or you do not even have a database created yet.

Comment: I have updated the question with the lsnrctl status. I see that the default servive is the XE which I thouhgt was correct. I also tried with the clrextproc and the Plsectproc but they didnt work.